# fatal error U1073: don't know how to make 'distclean' Stop

Tags: qt, nmake

Before configuring again qt with visual studio, I tried to cleanup previous build. I wrote cd C:\Qt\4.8.2 
C:\Qt\4.8.2>nmake distclean using Visual Studio Command Prompt(2010). Then I faced with this error.

How to fix this?

Comment: it gives the same error. instead of distclean there is clean

Answer (score 0):

It just means that you have already cleaned up your makefiles so configure your build once again to your liking.